# JS audio manipulation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have 4 audio elements, I need to make a next button that, when clicked, stops the current playing audio elements and plays the next one (they are set in order by id attribute).

The code "looks" fine, but it doesn't work. The browser (chrome) generates an error saying:

Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.

Here's the javascript:

```
$("#BtnNext").click(function(e){
        if(played != 0)
        {
            var selector = "A" + played;
            document.getElementById(selector).pause();
            document.getElementById(selector).currentTime = 0;
        };
        paused = 0;
        if(played == songNum || played == 0)
            played = 1;
        else if(played > 1)
            played++;
        var selector = "A" + played;
        document.getElementById(selector).play();
        selectme(played);
    });
```

Explanation:
paused: Number of the song that is currently paused
played: Number of the song that is currently played
songNum: How many songs in the document.
selectme(): Function that changes the color of the currently playing song (it works perfectly.

The error shows on this line:

```
document.getElementById(selector).currentTime = 0;
```

I don't believe there's a problem with the html part.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Nevermind, I just fixed it :)

Comment: It's generally nice to say what the fix was when you solve your own question. This site isn't just about you.